# How to encode a unichar array using NSCoding

Tags: cocoa, nscoding, nscoder

My custom object contains an array of `unichar` primitives.  However there is no `encodeUnichar:ForKey` method in NSCoder.  My solution is to transform my 2d `unichar` array into an `NSString` and then encode that.

However, the absence of a method to encode character makes me feel like I am missing something obvious, especially because I couldn't find the answer on Stack Overflow.

Before I embark on my NSString method, does anyone know if there is a simpler way to do this built in into the NSCoding protocol?

Thanks
Lee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A C array of fixed-size data is best encoded using `encodeBytes:length:forKey:`. See [Encoding and Decoding C Data Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingctypes.html) for full details.

Comment: This will work great until you try to decode the value on a machine with a different endianess. I know, all Apple machine are little-endian but that may change in the future (it already has).

Comment: You should swap the bytes before coding and after decoding with `NSSwapHostShortToLittle` and `NSSwapLittleShortToHost` or (`NSSwapHostShortToBig` and `NSSwapBigShortToHost` if you prefer big-endian).

Comment: This works great as long as you remember that a unichar is 2 bytes long!